# Svelte SMUI full screen dialog without content

Tags: svelte

The examples from [svelte dialog](https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/dialog/)

gives examples only for fullscreen dialog when the content fills the space. But I would like to use a select with many options that requires the full screen so as the opened select  have enough space. How to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the library. The drop-down of a select element should not be constrained by local layout. It should display on top of everything else and thus overflow the boundaries of the dialog.

This works as expected for native `<select>` elements but is broken for the `<Select>` component.

You can work around this to some degree by hacking the `Dialog` styling to show overflows. This will break layout if the "real" content is too large, though.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <Dialog ...>...</Dialog>
</div>

<style>
    .wrapper :global(.mdc-dialog__surface),
    .wrapper :global(.mdc-dialog__content) {
        overflow: visible;
    }
</style>
```

(The wrapper exists so the override is only applied locally and not to all dialog instances.)

[image: screenshot]

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/7d7624d5a9c24864a2810e6a761aa862?version=3.49.0)

Would recommend reporting this as an issue, if it has not been reported yet.

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me one more think? Why is the label coincides with the selected value (on leaving the select)? Both in your example and in my project. The bare.css is included.

Comment: The `value` of the `Option` components has to be a `string`, so for a number like in my example you can just use `i.toString()`. If you use an object you have to use the `key` functionality (see "Using Objects" in [the docs](https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/select)). I updated the REPL to fix that...